# How might I evaluate angular filters in ng-bind-html to format and display a defined HTML resource?

Tags: c#, angularjs, razor

I have run into a situation I could use some insight on. I have a defined resource that contains an HTML fragment and a format place holder (@Resource.Foo)...

```
<p>Been caught stealing on {0}</p>
```

I have a custom angular format filter (https://gist.github.com/litera/9634958)

In my .cshtml I have invoked, the following binding...

```
{{ '@Resource.foo' | format: ( ctrl.DateProperty | date: 'M/dd/yyyy' ) }}
```

As expected, the filters are executed correctly and {0} is replaced, however the HTML is not parsed

```
<p>Been caught stealing on 4/20/1977</p>
```

From research, the way angular will render the HTML appropriately is to throw it into an inline ***ng-bind-html*** attribute on an element. When I move the same string over to

```
<div ng-bind-html="'@Resource.foo' | format: ( ctrl.DateProperty | date: 'M/dd/yyyy' )"></div>
```

I get a big fat nothing. I wish I had a more advanced understanding of what is going on here, but my intuition would have thought the {{ implementation }} would be evaluated in the same manner as the ng-bind-html directive would evaluate what's being passed into it.

How can I use these filters AND get a properly parsed block of HTML to pop out the other end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell Angular that you are using `HTML` and that you `trust` it. Otherwise it just strips it out.

Angular provides this capability with the [`$sce` service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24sce).

You also use the `ng-bind-html` directive

Have a look at this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0tm5w7BXHDiSVLzAgCwF?p=preview) for a better idea. I have put 2 filters in place.

1 filter has `$sce` injected and calls the `.trustAsHtml()` method. The other doesn't.

You can see from the output that the `$sce.trustAsHtml(input)` is allowing the `html`. The other one has it all stripped by Angular.

For brevity the code from the plunker is here:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

});

app.filter("formatHtml", ['$sce', function($sce){
  return function(input){
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(input);
  };
}]);

app.filter("NOTformatHtml",function(){
  return function(input){
    return input;
  };
});
```

and the `html`

```
   <html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.17/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.2.17"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    html allowed: <br />
    You have <span ng-bind-html="'<b>Been caught stealing on 4/20/1977</b>' | formatHtml"></span>!
    <br/><br/>
    html stripped out by Angular<br />
    You have <span ng-bind-html="'<b>Been caught stealing on 4/20/1977</b>' | NOTformatHtml"></span>!
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your time on this one. I've got quite a string formatter filter set up now as a result. The $sce service was and continues to be a might obscure little feature. Cheers.

Comment: You're welcome :) and yep, took me ages to find out more info on that one too.